# Custom load data from .csv file to mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to load data from a csv file into mysql. The data format is 
book_id, author_name, title

sample data:
0070121430  Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest    Introduction to Algorithms

so when there are multiple authors i need to have a separate entry for each author with the same book_id and title .

I know how to do this using a Java file reader, but I'm looking for a way to do it using the LOAD command in mysql or HeidiSQL if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a temporary table with 3 columns for author, having NULL values for entries with one or two authors. I then used this temporary table to create a separate entry for each author name.